# Day add in SSRS for weekday

Tags: reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

i want to achieve the following I want to set the default date to the following business day. That would add one day for all weekdays unless it is Friday, if day is Friday than it add 3 days for Friday.

I am using the statement below but it is not working.  It is adding 3 days for other days besides Friday in ssrs report.

`= IIF(Weekday(Today()) <=3, DateAdd("d", 1, Today()), DateAdd("d", 3, Today()))`

> Example - 18/05/2018 today will be displayed  21/05/2018 And if date is 21/05/2018
>           then it will display  22/05/2018

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have created below logic on my local box and it works.

```
=DateAdd("d", IIF(Weekday(Today())=6, 3, IIF(Weekday(Today())=7, 2, 1)), Today())
```

I have added check that if `Weekday` returns 6(Friday) then add 3 days to `Today` date

else if `Weekday` returns 7(Saturday) then add 2 days to `Today` date

else add 1 day to `Today` date.